# Simple re-using a function jquery

Tags: jquery, function, selector, reusability

**Hello,

**How to reuse a jquery function for different variables?****

My working example allows a number of submissions to a form. When a threshold is reached - then the function hide the #form and shows a #block. It displays also a count a the number of submissions left.

My code can only manage one form - but I need multiple forms and thresholds.

**Can anyone help me how to set individually thresholds for each form???**

Each form (#form1, #form2, #form3) have each a counter (#entry_count1, #entry_count2, #entry_count3).

**I like to set:**

(threshold1)  for (form#1)

(threshold2)  for (form#2)

(threshold3)  for (form#3)

....

**Working code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var threshold1 = 30; // Set this to the # of entries to trigger on
var threshold2 = 12;
var threshold3 = 24;

var form1_to_hide = ["#form1”]; // CSS selectors of forms to hide when triggered
var form2_to_hide = ["#form2”]; 
var form3_to_hide = ["#form3”]; 
var block_to_show = [“#block”]; // CSS selector of block to show when triggered


// The function
$(function(){

$('#entry_count1’).on('changed.content', function(event){
var count1 = parseInt($('.ss_entry_count_value', this).text());
 var currentCount1 =  threshold1 - count1;


if(count1 >= threshold1){


$.each(form1_to_hide, function(i)
{
$(form1_to_hide[i]).hide();
});
$.each(block_to_show, function(i){
$(block_to_show[i]).show();
});
}

  if(count1 >= threshold1)
{
$.each(form1_to_hide, function(i){
$(form1_to_hide[i]).hide();
});
$.each(block_to_show, function(i){
$(block_to_show[i]).show();
});
}

$("#result1”).text(currentCount1);

});
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I am getting your question clear, but here is a shot:

What people that use jquery do a lot is use 'anonymous functions'. You'll see them like this:

```
$('someID').on('eventName', function() {
  // the anonymous function body
});
```

An anonymous function is (to my knowledge) the contradiction of re-using code. Because as it has no name, you can't really refer to it. ... Sure you can always do

```
var myFunction = function() {
  // anonymous function body
};
```

... to trap an anonymous function in a 'name'. But then I would say, just do it the 'normal' javascript way:

```
function myFunction() {
  // normal function body
}
```

To reuse this code in jquery, simply do:

```
$('someID').on('eventName', myFunction);
```

It will work with anonymous functions in a var, and with 'normal' functions.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use a an array to configure the values like,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var threshold_config = [ 
                            {limit: 30, forms_to_hide : ["#form1"], block_to_show:["block"] },
                            {limit: 12, forms_to_hide : ["#form2"], block_to_show:["block"] },
                            {limit: 24, forms_to_hide : ["#form3"], block_to_show:["block"] }
                        ];


// The function
$(function(){

    $('#entry_count1’).on('changed.content', function(event){
    var count1 = parseInt($('.ss_entry_count_value', this).text());
    var currentCount1 =  threshold1 - count1;

    $.each(threshold_config, function(index)
    {
        var threshold1 = threshold_config[index].limit;
        var form1_to_hide = threshold_config[index].forms_to_hide;
        var block_to_show  = threshold_config[index].block_to_show;
        if(count1 >= threshold1){


            $.each(form1_to_hide, function(i)
            {
                $(form1_to_hide[i]).hide();
            });
            $.each(block_to_show, function(i){
                $(block_to_show[i]).show();
            });
        }

        if(count1 >= threshold1)
        {
            $.each(form1_to_hide, function(i){
                $(form1_to_hide[i]).hide();
            });
            $.each(block_to_show, function(i){
                $(block_to_show[i]).show();
            });
        }

        $("#result1").text(currentCount1);

    });

    });

});

</script>
```

this should work, i have not tested it...